# Finding What Colour(s) Go Good With

Tags: css

### Current Admin Panel Themes

```
/** Portlet Colours Starts **/
    .Pink {             background: rgb(220, 79, 173); } 
    .Dark-Red {         background: rgb(172, 25, 61); } 
    .Dark-Orange {      background: rgb(210, 71, 38); } 
    .Orange {           background: rgb(255, 143, 50); } 
    .Light-Green {      background: rgb(130, 186, 0); }
    .Green {            background: rgb(0, 138, 23); }
    .Light-Teal {       background: rgb(3, 179, 178); }
    .Teal {             background: rgb(0, 130, 153); } 
    .Light-Blue {       background: rgb(93, 178, 255); } 
    .Blue {             background: rgb(0, 114, 198); } 
    .Purple {           background: rgb(140, 0, 149); } 
    .Dark-Purple {      background: rgb(105, 0, 112); } 
    .Medium-Dark-Blue { background: rgb(0, 75, 139); }
    .Dark-Blue {        background: rgb(0, 25, 64); }
    .Cordovan {         background: rgb(87, 0, 0); } 
    .Dark-Cordovan {    background: rgb(56, 0, 0); }
    .Grey {             background: rgb(204, 204, 204); }
    .Black {            background: rgb(0, 0, 0); }
/** Portlet Colours Ends **/
```

### The Problem / Question

I may have more than a dozen colours to deal with however getting the perfect colour combination on your website can be the make or break of a visitor staying or avoiding your website. I, may of times have gone onto a really ugly, bad colour combining websites in the past and instantly hit the back button on my mouse!

So what advice would you give to people trying to find those perfect colour combinations? - Dig out a colour chart maybe potentially wasting so much precious time or do you have a better solution?

Comment: This question is pretty interesting. However, it is not suited for StackOverflow because there is no programming issue to be solved (and you are asking us to recommend a tool, which is also not suited for S.O).

Comment: @JCOC611 Removed asking for a generator, thank you for pointing this out. I forget seeing people sometimes link to these. Instead I've modified for a personal view on helping finding the perfect colour combinations to suit my/a website.

Comment: So, it's an opinion-based, and non-programming, question? I'm afraid this remains off-topic here, but there's a *chance* that it may be on-topic for either [ux.se] or [graphicdesign.se]; but do check their help-pages first.

Comment: I guess this question is a bit of a doozy then @DavidThomas however saying that someone has linked an amazing useful tool so I would hope it stays up for future people to see their brilliant resource answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at these links. Type hex code or rgb and you can find similar colors or just colors which are good match.

http://www.colorblender.com/

http://paletton.com/

And my favorite:

https://color.adobe.com

Pick a **color rule** - **complementary**. Very useful tool!

---

***EDIT (nov. 2018):***

Nice new tool - https://colorkoala.xyz

Comment: could you explain how to use color rule - complementary a little please? Seems like a complex tool!

Comment: Think I've just worked it out. I have Adobe CC, never noticed this before now :)

Comment: Brilliant answer! You've saved myself and many more viewing this question A LOT of time!

Comment: under the _base_ color type your **rgb code** for some color and you get 4 complementary colors according to this adobe website :)